# jQuery Ajax form-box

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-ui, symfony

I have a list with several items and want to prevent the user from loading a new page for adding an item to this list.

My question now is how I bind in a window/box.
I found a jQuery-plugin "jQuery-ui-dialog" which creates boxes but I am unsure if I use this.

Another difficulty is the validation. Is it possible to use the Symfony2-Validation for Ajax requests?

Comment: not clear to me. I understand that if your list is on page A, the user goes to page B and adds a new item, your list on the page A stays the same and doesn't update or something. Confused.

Comment: Yeah I'm very confused by your question too, could you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

The jquery-ui dialog is one of a choices to solve this problem (you can as well just leave the normal form and send it via ajax - and it's a slighty easier solution, so I'd recommend you try to implement something like that first).

I did not use symfony ever, but it should be very easy to use its validation subsystem for ajax requests. Just remember, that they are normal requests - POSTs or GETs - that you have to handle yourself.

Those two resources should definitively give you some hints:

- [jQuery `ajax` funciton documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [jQuery `post` function documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: Hi,
thank you for youre speedy answers ;)

What about the format of the form?
When I just request the fallback-html-form I have to cut out all the overhead (I only want the form section) but the benefit is that I only have to manage one controller and one template.
The other solution would be to request the add-controller what response either a html-doc or a json. The json contains the validation-data and form object this solution would reduce the overhead but it makes it a bit harder.

What should I prefer

Comment: I'm personally using the second solution most often, though I saw quite often source code using the first one. Also note that you can check if the request was made via ajax and serve different content, so you don't have to use a separate controller.